# SQL Server Connection Issues with .NET 6

Tags: .net, sql-server, sqlclient

Does anyone know how to connect to a SQL server forcing NTML with a .NET 6 SqlClient connection string

```
var cnn = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder()
{
ApplicationIntent = ApplicationIntent.ReadWrite, 
DataSource = "[Server]",
InitialCatalog = "ProjectX", TrustServerCertificate = true
, UserID = "Domain\\UserName", Password = "******************"
};
```

Reason: Attempting to use an NT account name with SQL Server Authentication.

Comment: NTLM is used under certain circumstances when you use `Trusted_Connection=True;`

Comment: Interesting. 

Is that invoking the same permission set as something like 

[SomeDrive]:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /noprofile /netonly /user:[Domain]\[User] "[SomeDrive]:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe -S [host.mydomain.com]"

Thanks!

Comment: are you running your application on Linux environment ?